# In C# async and await the global variable crashed

Tags: c#

The C# app searches for a matching string in a folder with various excel files, each file with various rows and there might be various match strings found in each file. The result will be kept in a global variable. it worked perfectly
without async task but when I tried async/await, the global variable receive some wrong result. can I know how to solve this problem.

```
public IList<SearchList> SearchResult { get; private set; }
public async Task ReadExcelData(string stringSearch)        
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine("D:/test/", "Packing List Folder");
    SearchResult = new List<SearchList>();
    string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.xls*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();            
    foreach (var file in fileArray)
    {                        
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GetXlData(file, stringSearch)));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); 
}
```

---

```
private void GetXlData(string file, string stringSearch)
{  
     using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
     {
      // open the file and read every cells here.
                
      if (str == stringSearch)
      { 
        PList =sheet[row, col].Value2;
        unit =sheet[row, col+2].Value2;
        WriteData(PList, unit);
      }               
      workbook.Close();
      stream.Close();
}//how to made a return SearchResult in each task??
```

---

```
private void WriteData(string cde, string unt)
    { 
        SearchResult.Add(new SearchList
        {
            Code = cde,
            Unit = unt,
        });
    }
```

---

```
public class SearchList
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Code;
    }
}
```

this is the app structure I made..

Comment: you have multiple threads all writing to the SearchResult list.  Have you considered using a thread safe container such as ConcurrentBag?

Comment: Or let `GetXlData` return a `SearchList` instance then you can fill the list with `SearchResult.AddRange( await Task.WhenAll(tasks) );` in one go at the end

Answer (score 0):

First option is to use a lock

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

so you set the lock, access the global variable and release the lock again. So only one thread at a time can write to the variable. But I would not do this. Don't use global variables when dealing with threads.

Second option:
A task can return something.

after the `Task.WhenAll` you can iterate over your tasks and get the results (Result property in the task) and add them to your global variable.

Comment: i likes the second option. let GetXlData return a SearchList . i still digging into coding .can you teach or show me how to made it done.!! Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote code to return SearchList from GetXlData as plan but it show error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task', at
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GetXlData(file, stringSearch)));
Can help me solve this error. Thanks.

```
public IList<SearchList> SearchResult { get; private set; }
public async Task ReadExcelData(string stringSearch)
{
   string filePath = Path.Combine("D:/test/", "Packing List Folder");
   SearchResult = new List<SearchList>();
   string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.xls*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);                   
   List<Task<SearchList>> tasks = new List<Task<SearchList>>();
   foreach (var file in fileArray)
   {  
       tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GetXlData(file, stringSearch)));
   }
   var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   foreach (var item in results)
   {
      SearchResult.Add(item);
   }           
}

private List<SearchList> GetXlData(string file, string stringSearch)
{
    //i guess there is error here but unable fix this.
    List<SearchList> container = new List<SearchList>();
    using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
    {
       // open the file and read every cells here.
       if (str == stringSearch)
       { 
           WriteData(PList, unit);                         
       }                            
       container.AddRange((IEnumerable<SearchList>)WriteData(PList, unit));                                    
    }
    return container;
}

private SearchList WriteData(string cde, string unt)
    { 
        SearchList output = new SearchList
        {
            Code = cde,
            Unit = unt
        };            
        return output;
    }
```

grateful everyone support me..Thanks.